# how to get publish date from splistitem?

Tags: sharepoint-server

how to get the latest publish date from SPlistitem or SPfile?

```
 file.Versions[file.Versions.Count-1].Created.ToShortDateString();// fail
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the code below, it will only get the created time not the latest publish date.

```
file.Versions[file.Versions.Count-1].Created.ToShortDateString()
```

To get the latest publish date, you could refer to the code snippet.

```
item = list.GetItemById(itemId);
int count = item.Versions.Count;
SPListItem item1=item.Versions[count - 1].ListItem;
string date1 =item1["Modified"].ToString();
```